# Jasper API prints only first report other reports are printed as blank

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We are using jasper API (JasperFillManager.fillReport,JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile)

We want to execute that report in the loop with different parameters, so added following code

```
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
            // Fill report
            Iterator i1 = l1.iterator();
            Iterator i2 = l2.iterator();
            int i = 1;
            while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
                parameters.put("SUBJECTOID", (String) i1.next());
                parameters.put("HISTORYRECORD", (String) i2.next());
                try (ProfilePoint fillReport = ProfilePoint
                        .profileAction("ProfAction_ReportHelper_fillJasperReport")) {
                    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlPath);

                    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, emptyDataSource);
                    System.out.println("fillReport**********" + i);

                }

                // Export to PDF
                try (ProfilePoint exportReport = ProfilePoint
                        .profileAction("ProfAction_ReportHelper_exportJasperReport")) {
                    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                            "C:\\JASPER\\JASPEROUTPUT\\Report" + i + ".pdf");
                    System.out.println("exportReportToPdfFile**********" + i);
                }
                i++;
                jasperPrint = null;
                jasperReport = null;
```

So what happens we have 15 Parameteres , so 15 PDF files gets generated , but only first PDF file contains data, other 14 are blank.

We tried multiple things such as compiling once , compiling multiple times, extracted jasper code to method but still outcome is the same

Is there any cache or some kind of setting in jasper or similar something?

Comment: 1) Looks like you are passing empty datasource `JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, emptyDataSource);` 2) Maybe something wrong with your parameters `parameters.put("SUBJECTOID", (String) i1.next());` 3) You did not post full simple example - it is hard to help you. Maybe the *jrxml* is wrong; 4) `Is there any cache or some kind of setting in jasper or similar something?` - There is no cache. Did you check `jasperPrint` object on every iteration?

Comment: We are passing emptydatasource because in jrxml itself we are passing dataset as follow    `code new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource("http://i4515-vm2.ptcnet.ptc.com/Windchill/servlet/XML4Cognos?proc=com_ptc_windchill_enterprise_report_ReportTask%23QMS-CustomerExperience&SUBJECT_OID=OR%3acom.ptc.qualitymanagement.cem.CustomerExperience%3a"+$P{SUBJECTOID}+"&HISTORY_RECORD_OID=OR%3acom.ptc.windchill.history.HistoryRecord%3a"+$P{HISTORYRECORD}+"&uid=demo&locale=en-us&jasper=true","/dataset/data/row")`

Comment: so emptydatasource should not be the issue, we have  created two parameters to in jasper and same we have inserted in dataset url, we have added logger statements, and identified that parameters are getting passed correctly , but its very surprsing that loop only works for first iteration , from next iteration onwards it just prints empty PDF files, jrxml is quite big.

Comment: Do you create a new empty data source instance on each iteration, or use a single instance for all iterations?  The latter would not work because the data source instance gets consumed during report generation, you need to use e fresh instance each time, or at least rewind the data source with moveFirst().

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... Datasource you mean passed parameter `JREmptyDataSource emptyDataSource` right? I have passed that data source once only, do i need to create every time new? its empty datasource why it would matter?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new one every time.  A data source is like a java.util.Iterator, you can only use it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ dada67
for suggestion it worked

I have passed new emptydatasource for each iteration and it worked.

Thanks a lot..!!!